# Trouble with the Speech Recognition Grammar - VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, speech-recognition, grammar

When I try to load the grammar I made programatically I got an error:
**SAPI does not implement phonetic alphabet selection.**

My code:

```
Public Class Form1

Dim engine As New Speech.Recognition.SpeechRecognitionEngine  
Dim gram As new Speech.Recognition.Grammar("C:\Test\Speech\mygrammar.xml")      
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)   Handles MyBase.Load

Dim choices = New Recognition.Choices()

choices.Add("Red")
choices.Add("Blue")
choices.Add("Green")
choices.Add("Yellow")
Dim gb = New GrammarBuilder()

gb.Append(choices)

Dim doc = New Speech.Recognition.SrgsGrammar.SrgsDocument(gb)
IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\Test")
IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\Test\Speech")
Dim xWriter = System.Xml.XmlWriter.Create("C:\Test\Speech\mygrammar.xml")

doc.WriteSrgs(xWriter)
xWriter.Close()

Dim compiledFile = New FileStream("C:\Test\Speech\mycompiledgrammar.cfg", FileMode.OpenOrCreate)

Speech.Recognition.SrgsGrammar.SrgsGrammarCompiler.Compile("C:\Test\Speech\mygrammar.xml", compiledFile)
compiledFile.Close()
```

End Sub

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click  
engine.LoadGrammar(gram) 'There's the error  
engine.SetInputToWaveFile("D:\record.wav")  
End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using a Windows Pre-Vista (NT5)...
That error is due to SAPI version is not 5.3 or higher...
Test the code in Windows 7, everything should run OK...

You can see the problem in the librarty, lines 299 to 325, I'll pu the link below

[Source code for the .NET framework in C#, RecognizerBase.cs source code in C# .NET](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/DotNET/DotNET/8@0/untmp/WIN_WINDOWS/lh_tools_devdiv_wpf/Windows/wcp/Speech/Src/Recognition/RecognizerBase@cs/1/RecognizerBase@cs)

Stay well...